# single custom css for all posts Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have many posts with this style same for all ,

```
.total_data{
    padding-top:30px;
    height: 300px;
}
.image {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    padding-right:5px;

}
.data {
    float:left;
    width:65%;
}

h1 {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}
h3 {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.name{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.name_data{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    padding-top:5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me, just like we have simple css style sheet for simple websites, can i do that in wordpress with an plugin or otherwise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. To not have it clash with the Core-Styling of the active Theme (if you write your styling inside the main css, it may get overwritten on the next theme update), please create a child theme (you can do this with a plugin, just search for "child theme" inside the plugin directory), activate the child theme and then, you´ll have a css-file inside of your child-theme which you can use for your styling. This styling won´t get overwritten on theme updates. You can even create multiple css-files (desktop, mobile, etc) inside your child-theme-directory.

This should do the trick.

Comment: I added them in custom css without making the child theme and they worked fine thanks by the way